# Change label "username" to "account number" in WooCommerce registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account

I am trying to change "username" label on WooCommerce registration form to "account number" label. So when the data is exported, account numbers will become usernames.

I copied the following code and change it bit:

```
function woocommerce_reg_form() { 

add_filter( 'gettext', 'woocommerce_register_text' ); 
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'register_text' ); 
function register_text( $translating ) { 
    $translated = str_ireplace( 'Username or Email Address', 'Acc', $translating ); 
    return $translated; 
} 

add_action( 'woocommerce_registration_form' );
```

But it is giving me errors and doesn't work. What I am doing wrong? Please guide me.

Comment: function  woocommerce_reg_form() {
add_filter(  'gettext',  'woocommerce_register_text'  );
    add_filter(  'ngettext',  'register_text'  );
    function register_text( $translating ) {
         $translated = str_ireplace(  'Username or Email Address',  'Acc',  $translating );
         return $translated;
    }
add_action( 'woocommerce_registration_form' );

Comment: Please either put that commend in the post, or if that's the answer, probably delete your post since you found the answer all on your own, so others will be able to do so, too.

Comment: Override the template of registration in custom theme and make changes accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is totally incorrect. Use the following instead:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_registration_usename_label', 10, 3 );
function change_registration_usename_label( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
    if( is_account_page() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        if( $text === 'Username' ) {
            $translated = __( 'Account number', $domain );
        } elseif( $text === 'Username or email address' ) {
            $translated = __( 'Account number or email address', $domain );
        }
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you it actually works.. but when i added this function and clients registered their account number.. they are unable to place order during checkout. the page becomes grey

Comment: Hi in the first line is it that you purposely used the usename instead of username.. the code gives a fatal error in any way

Comment: Hi when i insert this line if( is_account_page() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) { it gives me fatal error is there any alternative code that can be used. i would be obliged if you can guide me

Comment: oh now i know what is the problem it is showing in wordpress login too all i want is in woocommerce registration and login form

Comment: @HurabNair My code uses [official WooCommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) that work just perfectly, if WooCommerce plugin is enabled. My code has nothing to do with your issue (this code is only active in WooCommerce registration).

Comment: I am so sorry sir i dont know why on my website its not working i just looked around and found another but it changes my wordpress login too is it possible that you help me with that to just replace the label of username 
 add_filter( 'gettext', 'register_text' );
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'register_text' );
function register_text( $translated ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace(
        'Username or Email Address',
        'Account Number or Email Address',
        $translated
    );
    return $translated;
}

Comment: @HurabNair So instead, you should override the template `myaccount/form-login.php` via your active theme, changing the required labels on it, as explained in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem hook as well as template overriding .

We can override template file in our active-child theme:

```
woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php


<?php
/**
 * Login Form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

<div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">

    <div class="u-column1 col-1">

<?php endif; ?>

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

            <p class="form-row">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox woocommerce-form-login__rememberme">
                    <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                </label>
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

    </div>

    <div class="u-column2 col-2">

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'account number', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
                </p>

            <?php else : ?>

                <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-FormRow form-row">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>
```

Hope , it will help you to resolve your problem other way.

Comment: Hi do i need to write it in cpanel first?

Comment: Hi i copied the temlate and copied you theme too but cannot see any changes in the frontend

Comment: Did you override parents theme into child?

Comment: What I did was copied from plugin woocommerce template form to avada theme login form and changed there